# R (and R Studio) ignoring Environment variables (default package library)

Tags: r

R is not granted writing rights to a network drive:

```
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="\\me-winserver/home$/bam/Documents/R/win-library/3.1": Access is denied
```

I receive some dozens of these errors/warnings when starting R-studio.

Workaround: I want to change the default library by manipulating the Environmental Variables in my Win7 system (add R_LIBS_USER to User variables with value ("C:\Users\bam\R\Library").

This is ignored, as demonstrated by .libPaths() and

```
> Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER")
[1] "//me-winserver/home$/bam/Documents/R/win-library/3.1"
```

Next step, i would like to manipulate Rprofile.site, but i do not really know, if i can use my absolute path in line:

```
 .Library.site <- file.path(chartr("\\", "/", R.home()), "site-library")
```

(and before i try, i would like to ask!)

This is true for R-Studio and R itself.

My questions:
1. Why is my R_LIBS_USER ignored?
2. How can i manipulate Rprofile.site properly?
3. Any other tricks?

This all happened when i received a new office PC; with my old PC i had the same problem, but could solve it via the environmental variable thing.

Of interest could be that (my default user has no admin rights) the Environmental Variables menu reads "User variables for ADMINISTRATOR", instead of my own Username. Is this the problem?

Comment: Well, yeah, I think you've answered your own question: it's a matter of having read/write permissions to the directories in question.

Comment: The solution really was the the the user variable needed to be set for each individual profile. I am very sorry for bothering.

Comment: No reason to be sorry.  Working out permissions stuff is a pain!

Comment: You can add a short note as an answer and accept it for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to not use "User Variables", but "System Variables", as the latter are profile-independant.
Changing "User Variables" for a given profile seem to require administrator rights for that profile (at least in our network setup).